# What to Substitute in a Lambda Calculus?

Tags: calculus, proof-explanation, education, substitution, lambda-calculus

I am confused firstly about how to differentiate between a bound variable and a free variable, so if someone could explain that with an example, that would be great.

Once I know the difference while making a substitution do I substitute the bound variables or the free variables?

Comment: @blargoner gives a good example below, but to approach this from a different perspective; are you familiar with the formal (inductive) definition of the free variables of a term?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loosely speaking, a free variable is one that is not bound by a $\lambda$ abstraction. For example, in $(\lambda x.x)$, $x$ is not free because it is bound by $\lambda x$, however in $(\lambda y.x)$, $x$ is free (where I here and below assume $x\ne y$).

When substituting a term for a variable, you want to substitute only for the *free occurrences* of the variable. However, you also need to make sure that the term you're substituting in is *free for substitution*, meaning it doesn't have a free occurrence of a variable which is bound in the expression into which it's being substituted. If not, you need to rename bound variables.

In the expression $(x(\lambda y.x))$ you give, $x$ is free and $y$ is bound. So the term $y$ is not free for substitution for the variable $x$ in this expression. In this case you can first rename $y$ to $z\ne y,x$ (say) to obtain $(x(\lambda z.x))$ and then substitute $y$ for $x$ to obtain $(y(\lambda z.y))$.

The result is not $(y(\lambda y.x))$ because that doesn't properly account for the second free occurrence of $x$ in the original expression. It is also not $(y(\lambda y.y))$ because that doesn't properly account for the renaming of the bound variable.